# installing HDF5 for C++

Tags: c++, cmake, hdf5

I'm trying to write a C++ program using HDF5, but I struggle with the build. It seems like cmake doesn't find the HDF5 library. Here is what I tried:

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <hdf5.h>

int main(){
    std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
}
```

CMakeLitsts.txt:

```
project(HelloWorld)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.27)

add_executable(hello_world main.cpp)

#  what do I have to do here? The find_package(HDF5 REQUIRED) fails as it doesnt find the HDF5 library
include_directories(${HDF5_INCLUDE_DIRS})
find_package(HDF5 REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries( hello_world ${HDF5_CXX_LIBRARIES} ${HDF5_LIBRARIES})
```

Running cmake fails with the error message

```
Could NOT find HDF5 (missing: HDF5_LIBRARIES HDF5_INCLUDE_DIRS) (found version "")
```

I downloaded and built HDF5 inside the folder `.local/hdf5` (I'm using Ubuntu) using

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
```

What step am I missing? Do I have to build it in another directory?

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue, and the fix (which I didn't like) was to use the below steps:

1. direct the compiler to the include folder wherever you built
2. use the compiler wrapper hdf5 uses

e.g. instead of executing the GCC binary

```
g++ your_code.cpp -o your_outpout.o
```

use the HDF5 wrapper

```
h5c++ -I ~/hdf5_install/HDF5-1.14.3-Linux/HDF_Group/HDF5/1.14.3/include/ your_code.cpp -o your_output.o
```